# Image Upload errors in Magento

Tags: magento

If you experience image upload errors after an upgrade or fresh install, try to amend the file:

```
root/lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php

from "chmod($destinationFile, 0640)" to "chmod($destinationFile, 0644)"
```

Any images you have already uploaded, please change file permissions manually to 644.

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: I fixed this error using above solution ty :)